# Translate macro by value before passing it as an argument to another macro

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

In the following example I want to replace the 2 in FOREACH(2, CREATE) by the TWO macro. How do I do that? Currently if i put FOREACH(TWO, CREATE), it will take TWO as a string instead of translating it to 2.

```
#define FOREACH1(f) f(0)
#define FOREACH2(f) f(1) FOREACH1(f)
#define FOREACH(n, f) FOREACH ## n(f)
#define TWO 2
#define CREATE(a) int c ## a;
FOREACH(2, CREATE);

int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
    c0 = 1;
    printf("sum = %d\n", c0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another level of macro expansion for `FOREACH`:

```
#define FOREACHX(n, f) FOREACH ## n(f)
#define FOREACH(n, f) FOREACHX(n, f)
```